# My controller url disappears when i use ajax as login

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am developing a site that has a login form and a newsfeed. when i use ajax as my action to submit values to the controller my controller url disappears instead of having mypage/newsfeed

here is the script im using

```
$('#submitButton').on('click',function(){
        var userid = $('#studentID').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        $('#errorHandler').empty();
        var URL = '<?php echo base_url('newsfeed')?>';

        if(userid.trim()!='' || password.trim()!=''){
            $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: URL,
            data:{userid:userid,password:password},
            success:function(data){
            if(data)
                $("body").load(data);
            },error:function(errorw){
                if( errorw.status == 400 ) { //Validation error or other reason for Bad Request 400
                  var json = $.parseJSON( errorw.responseText );
                }
                $('#errorHandler').append($('<label class="red-text text-darken-2">'+json+'</label>'));
            }
        });
        }else{
            $('#errorHandler').append($('<label class="red-text text-darken-2">ID/Password is Required</label>'));
        }
    });
```

UPDATE: controller code i am using custom routes `$route['newsfeed'] = 'Login/Login';`

```
public function Login(){
    $userid = $this->input->post('userid');
    $userpw = $this->input->post('password');
    $validate = $this->loginmodel->validateAccount($userid,$userpw);
    if($validate == NULL){
        $this->output->set_status_header('400');
        $details = $this->data['message'] = 'Incorrect Login/Password';
        echo json_encode($details);
    }
    else{
        $data['details'] = $this->loginmodel->getUserType($userid);
        if(is_array($data) || is_object($data)){
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $type = $value->accounts_type;
            }
        }
        $this->session->set_tempdata('accountID', $userid,18000);
        $userid = $this->session->tempdata('accountID');
        $data['init'] = $this->loginmodel->getGroups($userid);
        $data['groupId'] = $userid;
        if($type == "STUDENT"){
            $data['details'] = $this->loginmodel->getDetails($userid);
            $token = array(
                    'accountid' => $userid,
                    'groups' => $data['init'],
                    'details' => $data['details'],
                );
            $this->session->set_userdata($token);
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('sidenav1', $data);
        }
        elseif($type == "PROFESSOR"){
            $data['details'] = $this->loginmodel->getDetailsProf($userid);
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('sidenav2', $data);
        }
        elseif($type == "ADMIN"){
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('superadmin');
        }
        else{
            $data['details'] = $this->loginmodel->getDetails($userid);
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('Surveypage',$data);
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Could you post your controller's code?

Comment: i added the controller

Comment: see on console using `console.log(data)` inside ajax's success function.

Comment: you can not load `views` like this using ajax.You have to send response `data` from server then map into `DOM` using `js`or `jquery`.

Comment: ok thank you i got it